# If function And, OR to know if task is delay or not based on Today date - Excel

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu

Good morning

I have an issue writing a formula at excel,

I want to write an if statement ( if Today date > End date and status = In progress or Pending or new the result will be Delay )

- I have the status as a dropdown list
- this is a screenshot

[image]

Comment: Something like: if(and(today()>End_date,or(Progress_cell="In progress",Progress_cell="Pending",Progress_cell="New")),"Delay","") You can replace End_date with a cell as you wish, idem for Progress_cell. Not tested but the logic should be there.

Comment: Nice, But when I'm trying to change the end date to be on 15-Mar it's shows delay Also! while we are on 6th of Mar - so it's suppose to be no?

Comment: Are you sure all your dates are recognized as dates? and you could put >= if that is a better logic test instead of just =.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but the reason of this issue is the merged cell, when I separate them it's return the right answer.

Comment: Then don't merge cells...